# How to get unit tests to run in Maven Tycho build?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, tycho

I've done a lot of work in the past writing **unit tests** that run in "conventional" `Maven` builds, 
using JUnit and Mockito (and PowerMock).  I'm now working on an Eclipse plugin codebase, which builds with Maven Tycho.

Overall, it's a multiproject build, but I'm only adding **unit tests** to one of the plugin projects (for now).

I've heard of `tycho-surefire`, but that seems pretty complicated, and it really sounds more like it supports integration tests instead of **unit tests**.  I'm guessing I'll probably have no choice but to use this, but so far I haven't tried to integrate it.

I tried getting the JUnit and Mockito artifacts from Maven, and then using the `maven-dependency-plugin` to get the artifacts available to be referenced in the `Bundle-Classpath` property of the manifest.

When I run the build, the `tycho-compiler-plugin` I see it **compiling 105 source** files, which includes all of the classes in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. 
 It fails to `compile` the test class because it can't find the `Mockito` classes, even though when I run the build with `-X`, it shows the `mockito-all` artifact in the **dependency** tree.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of painful Maven trial & error I struggled across [this website](https://mukis.de/pages/simple-junit-tests-with-tycho-and-surefire/), which provides a surprisingly easy way to use unit-tests in a Maven-Tycho setup.

Here, the important parts of the `pom.xml` when using JUnit (probably looks similar for Mockito):

```
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compiletests</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Name all your tests in a way so that they end with `*Test.java`. Run `mvn test` in order to execute all available unit-tests.

Comment: Hello Alex! Is this configuration supposed to go in a Maven module with Tycho's `eclipse-test-plugin` packaging? On in a non-Tycho maven module?

Comment: Also, can the tests in this configuration use dependencies from the Eclipse plugin `MANIFEST.MF` file? Or do you have to declare all dependencies for you test code in your Maven pom file?

Comment: For JUnit 5 and/or mixed Junit 4 and 5: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/JUnit5

Comment: It's a bit absurd that I need to consult a 9+ year old blog to find a working guide to something so fundamental as unit testing... Thanks anyway, very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You have to use junit and Mockito as osgi bundles

I think this Question answered detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122834/which-dependencies-do-i-need-to-use-mockito-and-junit-in-an-eclipse-rcp-tycho-pr)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually no. You dont "have to" go through this hell. It's just another, more complicated option. See my answer